# How can I set 2 approvals specific to a branch for 2 different conditions on project level in BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket

I want 2 approvals before merging a PR for a specific branch on BitBucket project level settings with following conditions.

1. One approval from one of the five DLs (group of users to review) that we have
2. Second approval should be open to everyone who is having access to our project

I did find some settings in workflow options and merge checks available under project settings but these are being applied to all the branches. Is there any way where I can get the required setting specific to a branch ?

Comment: Are you using the Cloud solution? You can find what you want under Branch Restrictions